# How to pass function with parameters as a prop?

Tags: reactjs

I want to write a custom logic to determine which `<NavLink>` is active one. So I do following:

```
handleIsActive(match, location) { ... }

render() {
    return <NavLink isActive={this.handleIsActive} />
}
```

This works perfect. But how do I send more information into `handleIsActive`? Ex:

```
<NavLink isActive={this.handleIsActive(product_id)} /> // Does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<NavLink isActive={(match, location) => this.handleIsActive(match, location ,product_id)} />
```

and handle function like this

```
handleIsActive(match, location, product_id) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a solution

```
<NavLink isActive={() => this.handleIsActive(product_id)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the function `this.handleIsActive(product_id)` and using the returned value as `isActive` prop, So what you are doing is this, (assuming you don't return anything from `this.handleIsActive`)

```
<NavLink isActive={undefined} />
```

You need to pass a reference to a function like so

```
<NavLink isActive={() => this.handleIsActive(/* insert arguments here */)} />
```